# HBase schema design in storing query log

Tags: search, schema, hbase

Recently, I'm working on make a solution for storing user's `search log`/`query log` into a HBase table.

Let's simple the raw Query log:

```
query timestamp req_cookie req_ip ...
```

Data access patterns:

1. scan through all querys within a time range.
2. scan through all search history with a specified query

I came up with the following row-key design:

```
<query>_<timestamp>
```

But the query may be very long or in different encoding, put `query` directly into the `rowkey` seems unwise.

I'm looking for help in optimizing this schema, anybody handling this scenario before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You can do a full table scan with a timerange. In case you need realtime responses you have to maintain a reverse row-key table `<timestamp>_<query>` (plan your region splitting policy carefully first).

> Be warned that sequential row key prefixes will get some of your
>   regions very hot if you have a lot of concurrence, so it would be wise
>   to buffer writes to that table. Additionally, if you get more writes than a single region can handle you're going to implement some sort of sharding prefix (i.e modulo of the timestamp), although this will make your
>   retrievals a lot more complex (you'll have to merge the results of
>   multiple scans).

2- Hash the query string in a way that you always have a fixed-length row key without having to care about encoding (MD5 maybe?)

Comment: It will work perfectly, you'll get 25byte rowkeys, which isn't small but it's not too bad. Only in extreme cases when you need smaller rowkeys you can extract just the 4-8 first characters from the hash, but then you're going to get the same hash from multiple different queries, which shouldn't be a problem if you store the original query in one of the columns so you can add a SingleColumnValue filter to discard unwanted queries (8 byte hashes should be more than enough to get a minimal amount of collisions).